# Transpose Album names for a bunch of MP3 files

Tags: mp3, metadata

I am looking for a script or tool that can move around elements of the Album name of a big bunch of mp3 files.

They currently have Album names like:   1999 - The Music of Canada

I would like the Album names to be: Canada (1999) Music of

There are around 200 albums that I need to rename.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install tagtool
```

It's very easy to use. Just select the files and then edit their metadata.

[image]

Comment: What is particularly nice about this tool is its ability to extract track numbers and names from the file name and apply this to the metadata for a group of mp3s all at once. Thanks for this answer.